# How to automatically export data from Postman to Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, export, postman, e2e-testing

I want to run and export JSON data with test automatically from Postman. Here I read that this impossible: http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/09/03/how-to-write-powerful-automated-api-tests-with-postman-newman-and-jenkins/ , but maybe something have changed? 
Maybe somebody know how i can do this?

Now I writing test in Postman expansion for Chrome Driver. After collection is created I push "Export" button. After that I save JSON file to git repository and point it in Jenkins.
My goal is run test in Jenkinks using only collection id or something like this. Without saving in separate project.

Comment: Please show us your current approach.

Comment: @aggsol I clarified my question, thank you.